Wierd color issue in browser, color-picker indicates different color then assigned in HTML
In my CSS code I have defined a background-color for a piece of text as the snippet below.
Now when I use the color picker of PowerToys or just take a screenshot and use the color picker of paint or any other tool, e.g., GIMP. All give a different, but the same, color then I defined in the HTML.
I figured out the issue is in Microsoft Edge, Firefox displays OK. Resetting the browser Microsoft Edge doesn't seem to do anything.
I have no clue what is going on here...?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:#00a3e0">Some text</div>
</body>
</html> 



